# how do I get items from listview to use them in combobox

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-express

I try to get the items from a listview to use them in a combobox, so I can select one of them to create an order. Im my application I use 3 listview in separate forms to store some informations. Based on the informations stored there I want to create a order.
I'm using visual c++ 2008 express.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using the plain Win32 API, you use [`LVM_GETITEM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774953%28VS.85%29.aspx) / [`LVM_GETITEMTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761055%28VS.85%29.aspx) / [`LVM_GETNEXTITEM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761057%28VS.85%29.aspx) messages by sending them to the control.
Alternatively you can use the convencience macros [`ListView_GetItem()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761308%28VS.85%29.aspx) / `ListView_GetItemText()` / `ListView_GetNextItem()`.